# Append element to Firebase Array

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How I could append an element to an array like that:
[image]

Using this code I'm overriding the old data:

```
let toUpdate = [book.id]
self.refUsers.child(localUser.key!).child("booksPurchased").setValue(toUpdate, withCompletionBlock: { (error, _) in
```

Comment: Every time you use an array in concurrently modified data, a puppy dies.

Comment: Check the doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In this case, you will have to read the existing data, then write it back with the new value added.  Arrays like this are not always the best way to store lists of data if you want to perform a lot of append operations.  For that, you're better off [pushing data into a location using childByAutoId](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data).

Answer (score 17):

You could use this method: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion()

Example with angularfire2:

```js
this.afs.collection('collection').doc(id).update( {
   array: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion( 'newItem' )
});
```

For more information: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#arrayunion

Comment: that is for firestore not realtime db

Comment: New url for that would be https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array

Answer (score 2):

You could set the values of the keys in the array to `true`, and then set the value directly in an update.

So if 'newId' is the new item to add, maybe something like:

```
const update = {
   [`/users/${localUser.key}/booksPurchased/${newId}`]: true]
}
firebase.db.ref().update(update);
```

Firebase docs example of an update:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: This helped me but the question is about iOS and I think you posted the solution for the web.

Comment: but the result wouldn't be Array, its better to use childByAutoId than boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Reading and writing lists
Append to a list of data

Use the childByAutoId method to append data to a list in multiuser applications. The childByAutoId method generates a unique key every time a new child is added to the specified Firebase reference. By using these auto-generated keys for each new element in the list, several clients can add children to the same location at the same time without write conflicts. The unique key generated by childByAutoId is based on a timestamp, so list items are automatically ordered chronologically.

You can use the reference to the new data returned by the childByAutoId method to get the value of the child's auto-generated key or set data for the child. Calling getKey on a childByAutoId reference returns the auto-generated key.

You can use these auto-generated keys to simplify flattening your data structure. For more information, see the data fan-out example.

-https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data