# Storing custom objects with array of custom objects in Firebase: Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How would I achieve this setup in Firebase Realtime Database with Swift:

Database hierarchy

[image]

Currently, I am doing this by storing the larger element (with properties familyKey, geofences, and phoneNumbers) as a custom object. Also, the geofences property itself is an array of custom objects. I get an NSException doing this in the described fashion. How else would I go about doing this?

```
    var tempGeofences = [GeofenceData]()
    tempGeofences.append(GeofenceData(name: "Hello WOrld", latitude: 0, longitude: 0, radius: 1000))

    let familyKey:String = String(Int.random(in: 1000...99999))
    let uid:String = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    let phoneNumber = "1111111111"
    let parent = Parent(phoneNumber: phoneNumber, familyKey: familyKey, geofences: tempGeofences)

    databaseRef.child(uid).setValue(parent)
```

The NSException is thrown on this line:

```
databaseRef.child(uid).setValue(parent)
```

Parent class:

```
import Foundation

public class Parent {
var phoneNumber: String?
var familyKey: String?
var geofences: [GeofenceData]?

init() {
    self.phoneNumber = ""
    self.familyKey = ""
    self.geofences = nil
}

init(phoneNumber: String?, familyKey: String?, geofences:[GeofenceData]) {
    self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
    self.familyKey = familyKey
    self.geofences = geofences
}

public func getPhoneNumber() -> String {
    return phoneNumber!
}

public func getFamilyKey() -> String {
    return familyKey!
}

public func getGeofences() -> [GeofenceData] {
    return geofences!
}

// left off here, trying to send geofence object to firebase
public func toDictionary() -> Any {
    return ["familyKey": familyKey, "geofences": geofences, "phoneNumber": phoneNumber]
}
```

}

And the GeofenceData class:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

public class GeofenceData {
var name: String?
var latitude: Double?
var longitude: Double?
var radius: Float?

init() {

}

init(name: String?, latitude: Double, longitude: Double, radius: Float) {
    self.name = name
    self.latitude = latitude
    self.longitude = longitude
    self.radius = radius
}

// left off here, trying to send geofence object to firebase
public func toDictionary() -> Any {
    return ["name": name, "latitude": latitude, "longitude": longitude, "radius": radius]
}

public func getName() -> String {
    return name!
}

public func getLatitude() -> Double {
    return latitude!
}

public func getLongitude() -> Double {
    return longitude!
}

public func getRadius() -> Float {
    return radius!
}

public func setName(name: String?) {
    self.name = name
}

public func saveToFirebase(reference: DatabaseReference) {
    let dict = ["name": name, "latitude": latitude, "longitude": longitude, "radius": radius] as Any
    reference.child("geofences").child("0").setValue(dict)
}
```

}

Comment: Please add your code in question and mention where you are getting NSException so that we can help you.

Comment: Hi Bhaumik, I am out of town at the moment, but I can give you as much detail as possible. Basically, I have a class that has properties of familyKey, geofences, and phoneNumber, where geofences is an array of another custom object, which has properties longitude, latitude, name, and radius. The NSException is thrown on the line where I am am saving my data to firebase via setValue(object)

Comment: The error is because you cannot store user defined objects in Firebase, OR *object* is nil. However, without seeing  your code we're just guessing. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Update your question with your code and we'll take a look!

Comment: Hi, I just updated my post!

Comment: As you can see, in the saveToFirebase() function for a GeofenceData object, I had to hardcode the index 0 to create the array of GeofenceData objects in Firebase. In Android, I could just do "setValue(parent)" and it would work perfectly fine.

Comment: My comment from above still holds true - *Parent* is not an object that Firebase recognizes so it throws an error. The Firebase guide [Reading & Writing Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write) shows the four types of objects that can be written; String, Number, Dictionary, Array. A *Parent* object is not in that list. To fix that, I would suggest creating a function within the Parent object that returns a dictionary of the items you want to write - then call that function and write the returned dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Parent* is not an object that Firebase recognizes so it throws an error.

The Firebase guide [Reading & Writing Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write) shows the four types of objects that can be written; String, Number, Dictionary, Array.

One solution is to build a function into the class that returns the data you want to write.

```
public class Parent {
    var phoneNumber: String?
    var familyKey: String?
    var geofences: [GeofenceData]?

    init() {
        self.phoneNumber = ""
        self.familyKey = ""
        self.geofences = nil
    }

    //other init functions

    func getParentDict() -> [String: Any] {

        let geoDict = ["name": name,
                       "latitude": latitude,
                       "longitude": longitude,
                       "radius": radius
        ]

        let zeroNode = ["0": geoDict]

        let dictForFirebase: [String: Any] = [
            "phoneNumber": phoneNumber,
            "familyKey": familyKey,
            "geofences": zeroNode
        ]

        return dictForFirebase
    }
}
```

and in practice

```
var tempGeofences = [GeofenceData]()
tempGeofences.append(GeofenceData(name: "Hello WOrld", latitude: 0, longitude: 0, radius: 1000))

let familyKey:String = String(Int.random(in: 1000...99999))
let uid:String = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
let phoneNumber = "1111111111"
let parent = Parent(phoneNumber: phoneNumber, familyKey: familyKey, geofences: tempGeofences)
let parentDict = parent.getParentDict
databaseRef.child(uid).setValue(parentDict)
```

However, one concern is the child node with "0" as the key. That looks like you may be using an array. If there's a good reason that's fine but there are usually much better alternatives to using array's in NoSQL databases. See the legacy but still  accurate Firebase post called [Arrays Are Evil](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)

**EDIT:**

Per a comment/question 'how to add another child node following the "0" node"

Assume we know the parent node, qSaEE..., lets add a "1" node

```
let parentNode = "qSaEE..."
let geofenceRef = firebaseRef.child(parentNode).child("geofences")

let geoDict = ["name": name,
               "latitude": latitude,
               "longitude": longitude,
               "radius": radius
               ]

let oneNode = ["1": geoDict]

geofenceNode.setValue(oneNode)
```

Comment: Hi Jay, when I upload the Parent object from Android, it automatically adds the "0" node seeing that "geofences" is an Array of GeofenceData objects. To parallel android, I  would need to replicate this database structure for iOS. How would I do that?

Comment: Also, in my bigger node, my three properties are familyKey, geofences, and phoneNumber. Wouldn't the setup you provided give me three properties of familyKey, 0, and phoneNumber?

Comment: One last thing, I want a Parent object to be able to hold multiple GeofenceData objects, hence why I am using an array of GeofenceData objects as a property of a Parent. In the example above, we are only creating a dictionary for one Geofence data and storing that under the node "0". How would I make it flexible enough, so if I wanted to add to that array at a later point, I could add another GeofenceData object under the node "0"? Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: @pavpanda I missed that 0 node so I updated the code to provide the exact structure.

Comment: @pavpanda and I updated it to answer your second question about adding another node following the "0" node

Comment: Thanks @Jay . At the moment, we are hardcoding in the indices of the Geofence objects. Let's say we had an array of GeofenceData objects  with length n that we wanted to append to the already existing "geofences" node. If we already have a GeofenceData object at indices 0 and 1, how would we programmatically append the length-n GeofenceData array to the "geofences" node (with nodes 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., n + 1)?

Comment: @pavpanda A for...loop would be an option if you know the number of children you want. Another option is to read the nodes and take the highest number key and then add 1 to generate the next key. There are a number of other solutions but remember that when working with Firebase arrays, there is no 'append item to an array function'. To add a node, you either need to do one of the two aforementioned techniques or read in the entire array, append in code and save it back out. See a Firebasers answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49196979/append-element-to-firebase-array)