# How to store complex JSON data into the firebase realtime database using flutter

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

I'm new at Flutter and I'm trying to handle the complex json structure but i dont know how to store complex JSON data into the firebase realtime database using flutter.Here I attached my JSON structure and Data model class structure too. Are there are any related article or tutorialregarding the same.

```
JSON Structure:
{
  "users": {
    "John@gmail.com": {
      "name": "John Doe",
            "Country": "United Kingdom",
        "verified_phone": true,
        "ID_verification": False,
    },
      "Properties": {
        "Properties":[ {
        "propertiename":"Hilton_Common",
                        "Role" : "owner"},
    {"propertiename":"Carraige_guest_house",
                        "Role" : "staff",
            }
    ....
    ....
    ]},
      "Reservations": {
    "Properties": [{
         "propertiename":"Hilton_Common"
                        "Guest" : "Primary_guest"},
    {"propertiename":"Carraige_guest_house"
                        "Guest" : "Aditional",
        }
    ....
    ....
    ]},
          }}

User model:

class User {
  String key;
  final List<Host> host;
  final List<User_Reservation> reservation;
  String nameformlogin, phone, email;
  String verifiedphone, idverification;
  var list;
  User({
    this.key,
    this.nameformlogin,
    this.phone,
    this.email
    this.verifiedphone,
    this.idverification,
    this.host,
    this.reservation,

  });

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {

    return new User(
        nameformlogin: json["nameformlogin"],
        phone: json["phone"],
        email: json["email"],
        verifiedphone: json["verifiedphone"],
        idverification: json["idverification"],
        host: json["host"],
        reservation:json["reservation"]
        );
  }

  toJson() {
    return {
        'name': nameformlogin,
        'county':phone,
        'email': email,
        'verifiedphone':verifiedphone,
        'idverification':idverification,
        'host':host,
    'reservation':reservation

    };
      }
}
class Host {
  String propertiesname, role;
  Host({this.propertiesname, this.role});
  factory Host.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new Host(propertiesname: json['propertiesname'], role: json['role']);
  }
}
class User_Reservation {
  String propertiesname, guest;
  User_Reservation({this.propertiesname, this.guest});
  factory User_Reservation.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new User_Reservation(
        propertiesname: json['propertiesname'], guest: json['guest']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

create instance of Realtime Database (rtd) reference,
Store data with as key value:

```
void storeData{
      dataBaseRef.child(user.key).set({
         "name":user.name,
         "host":user.host,
         ...
      });
}
```

If u don't know how to connect and create a reference of RTD, you can refer this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l8_7RTRRmHo)

Comment: The variable name is not a problem. It is a simple string variable and I am able to store it in the database. The actual problem here for eg: host which is an array of a complex variable with structure------      class Host {
  String propertiesname, role;
  Host({this.propertiesname, this.role});
  factory Host.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new Host(propertiesname: json['propertiesname'], role: json['role']);
  }............................................................Could you please provide a suggestion about how to store a complex variable(class within a class)?

Comment: @feathersoft when you use user.host (class within a class) to store the array of host object it will be stored successfully, have u tried once with the above code ?

Comment: @sumeetJain, I have tried but not able to save. But it didn't work. Do you have any sample code for saving data like <list> of class within another class?

Comment: @feathersoft i got the problem now, you need to run a loop over the list <class> create a key value pair of all the properties of the object inside list <class> and then add to the RTD with unique index. This might help you  
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55034729/storing-custom-objects-with-array-of-custom-objects-in-firebase-swift

Comment: @sumeetJain, Do you have any flutter code to handle complex class