# How to reconcile array creation with array appending?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

At one point in my code I'm creating a node in my realtime db like so:

```
const ref = await lobbyGamesRef.push({
  players: [{ uid: context.auth.uid }],
  // other properties omitted, but there's like 6 in all
});
```

It's an array of one because the host has just created a game and so is currently the only person in it.

When another player goes to join, I'm running this code:

```
await db.ref(`/lobbyGames/${data.gameKey}/players`).push({
  uid: context.auth.uid
});
```

The result, as someone familiar with realtime db might predict, is this:
[image]

The array gets created initially with numeric indices, and then `push` creates an id for the next thing instead of continuing the indices.

I saw in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49196979/append-element-to-firebase-array) that `childByAutoId` is recommended, but after reading the [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseReference#/c:objc(cs)FIRDatabaseReference(im)childByAutoId) on it I honestly couldn't see how it would be used here.

Ideally I would like to have either all numeric or all uuid keys, idk. I just want consistency! And I'd rather not have to read the property just to write to it, that's not too efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use push at all, you have to use it consistently.  You won't be able to pass an array to initially populate the child.  For example, you probably want to do this:

```
const ref = await lobbyGamesRef.push().child("players").push({
  uid: context.auth.uid
});
```

Comment: Apologies, I might be misunderstanding you, but push returns a `ThenableReference` which [does not have](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ThenableReference) a `ref` method, only a `ref` property-- I assume I'm misunderstanding. I think `child` would work though...? Maybe~ trying it now~

Comment: I updated to use child() instead to build on to the reference created by push().

Answer (score 0):

As the Firebase Realtime database specify, it will automatically generate a unique ID whenever you push a new item into the array
[image]

In your situation, when you first initialize, your `Ref` is pointing to a specific game, later on, when you add a new player, your `Ref` is pointing to the players array of a specific game. I would suggest when you first added a game, just initialize your players with an empty array and call push() in a separated function